# wrong bitmap after scale with renderOptions

Tags: wpf, datagrid, dialog, render, blur

In **dialog**, I need to scale bitmap in cell of datagrid for avoid *bluring*

here is MyFile.xaml

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Margin="1"
                                   Width="90"
                                   Height="18"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Stretch="Fill"
                                   RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
                                   RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HatchIdToPaleteImageConverter}" ConverterParameter="90">
                                        <Binding Path="HatchId"/>
                                        <Binding Path="Color" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

But bitmaps in 5th, 20th row are *hidden* their top but the others are OK.
If I **scroll** my grid by vertical scrollbar, the hidden image changed: bitmaps in 11st, 26th row are *hidden* their top but the others are OK. I guess the 5th, 20th datagridcell of view is always wrong.

If I remove `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"`

the bitmap in all rows are showed full but it's blur.

I try to remove the margin or resize my row's height but it's not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change height of Image. It's work.
Maybe the height of bitmap is not the same between all row of datagrid

```
Height="19"
```